# How is the Linux kernel stack organised for ARM architecture?

Tags: linux, kernel

Can any one explain how exactly linux kernel stack organisation is handled?

When a child process is created using the `fork()` system call, how is the kernel stack space initialized?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you talking about kernel thread stacks or something else? What do you mean by "organised"?

Comment: Sounds to me like a question about memory / address space layout.